# PHPUnit Test result type or also the result variables

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

during unit testing i'm always get confused about what to test.
Do i need to test the API and only the API or also the method result values.

```
class SomeEventHandler
    {
        public function onDispatch (Event $event)
        {
            if ($event->hasFoo)
            {
                $model = $this->createResponseModel('foo');
            }
            else
            {
                $model = $this->createResponseModel('bar');
            }

            // End.
            return $model;
        }

        private function createResponseModel ($foo)
        {
            $vars = array(
                'someVare' => true,
                'foo'      => $foo
            );

            // End.
            return new ResponseModel($vars);
        }
    }
```

So should i test if the method `onDispatch` returns a instance of `ResponseModel` or should i also test if the variable foo is set properly?

Or is the test below just fine?

```
    class SomeEventHandlerTest
    {
        // assume that a instance of SomeEventHandler is created
        private $someEventHandler;

        public function testOnDispatch_EventHasFoo_ReturnsResponseModel ()
        {
            $e         = new Event();
            $e->hasFoo = true;

            $result = $someEventHandler->onDispatch($e);

            $this->assertInstanceOf('ResponseModel', $result);
        }

        public function testOnDispatch_EventHasNoFoo_ReturnsResponseModel ()
        {
            $e         = new Event();
            $e->hasFoo = false;

            $result = $someEventHandler->onDispatch($e);

            $this->assertInstanceOf('ResponseModel', $result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were checking the code by hand what is it that you would check?  Just that a ResponseModel was returned or that it also had the proper values?

If you weren't writing tests and executed the code what would you look for to ensure that the code was doing what it was supposed to.  You would check that the values in the returned object were correct.  I would do that by using the public API of the object and verify that the values are right.

One idea is to have the tests such that if the code were deleted, you would be able to recreate all the functionality via only having the tests.  Only checking the returned object could result in a function that just has `return new ResponseModel();`.  This would pass the test but would not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In short, what you decide to test is subjective, however you should at the minimum test all your public methods.

Many people limit their tests to public methods and simply ensure code coverage on the protected/private methods is adequate. However, feel free to test anything you think warrants a test. Generally speaking, the more tests the better.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should certainly test for your response data, not just the return type.

I rely on Unit Tests to let me make code changes in the future and be satisfied my changes have not created any breaks, just by running the tests.

So in your case, if the "foo" or "bar" response data is important, you should test it.

That way if you later change the response strings by accident, your tests will tell you.